# If 19 numbers of 24

Tags: python

I have 24 numbers that I don't know.

```
X1=int(input("Number:"))
X2=int(input("Number:"))
...
X23=int(input("Number:"))
X24=int(input("Number:"))
```

If 7 of them are number 3 than the answer is true.

How can I write '7 of these numbers'?

Comment: Are they really all in different scalar variables? Not a list or something?

Comment: You shouldn't use 24 separate variables for that, that will make writing the code that uses them overly complicated. You should put your numbers in a list.

Comment: These should be in a list, then this is trivial. Do `xs = [int(input("Number:")) for _ in range(25)]` to get 25 numbers, then you can just iterate over the list to check. This will be incredibly complicated if you try to use separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```py
lst=[X1,X2,...,X24]
if lst.count('3')==7:
    #do some stuff
```